# Can I open new form while running Unit tests?

Tags: winforms, unit-testing

what I want to do is to create form dynamically while running unit test. The actual form would only act as a progress bar. My unit test are using Selenium library to test websites and it would be good to have some sort of progress bar. I have tried to create new form in the middle of test, but while the test is performing, the form just hangs in there. Thx!

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void test1()
    {     
        using(Form1 form=new Form1())
        {
            form.Show();
            form.RunAsync();
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(doSomeThing());
    }
```

And this is what form would do for now. This is just example ! The backgroundworker should fill the progress bar, however, once the form shows up, it just freezes

```
BackgroundWorker bw;

 private void RunAsync()
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       or (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);                     
            bw.ReportProgress(i);              
        }           
        bw.ReportProgress(100);
    }
```

Comment: can you show us your code? i suspect it's thread management problem

Comment: next time if you want people to know you've edited the post, write a comment, i don't know otherwise...

Comment: sorry, my bad. I'll make sure I do it next time

Comment: Are you looking to provide a progress bar per test or for the entire test run?

Comment: I wanted to add it per test. Basically leave the option to show it or no, because some of the tests are so short there is no need for bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple progress bar example

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
     backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1;
     backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged_1;
     Load += Form1_Load_1;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the BackgroundWorker.
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
    // Wait 100 milliseconds.
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    // Report progress.
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    // Set the text.
    this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}
```

notice the difference: your background worker do some work, and report it, but no one catches it or you're not showing all your code. anyway, you can take this code

Comment: You are right, I am not showing all of my code because I do not think it's very relevant. What I am trying to find out is how to create form inside the unit test so it would not be blocked

Comment: @Tomas this code does exactly that. you can replace your code with this if you don't want to show the rest of the code or you can seach which event isn't handeled in your code

Comment: This is a valid code on it's own. But if you try to create this form inside the unit test it just freezes. Maybe I am doing something wrong.